# Query of Queries syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, qoq

I have to get records from a Query using Query of Queries in my F/W1 application. Im running it in coldfusion 10. My Query is as follows,

```
<cfquery name="qryFormData" dbtype="Query">
      Select * from qryFormfields where language = 'ENG'
</cfquery>
```

And I'm getting this error

```
 ERROR!

An error occurred!
Action: locations.default
Error: Error Executing Database Query.
Type: Database
Details:
Query Of Queries syntax error.
Encountered "language. Incorrect conditional expression, Expected one of [like|null|between|in|comparison] condition,
```

What I'm doing wrong? Any Help would be appreciated.

My Query is so simple as follows

```
<cfquery name="qryFormfields" datasource="#variables.dsn#">
    SELECT cf.CustomFieldID, cfl.label,cfl.language,cf.Type FROM CustomFields cf 
    INNER JOIN CustomFieldLabels cfl ON cfl.CustomFieldID = cf.CustomFieldID
    AND Entity = <cfqueryparam  value="#arguments.tablename#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
    WHERE Language = <cfqueryparam  value="#SupportedLangID.prefix#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
    AND SiteID = <cfqueryparam  value="#arguments.SiteID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
</cfquery>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`LANGUAGE` is a reserved word in query on query. See the docs here: [Query of Queries user guide: Escaping reserved keywords](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0e4fd-7ff0.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7008).

So you'll need to alias that column in your original query (or escape it with square brackets, as per the docs).

Comment: Thank you, I thought so but was unsure. Which is why I wanted him to debug. =]